# Mockgen Error while trying to autocreate mock_interface with it

Tags: go

I'm making mock_interface.go file with the help of Mockgen, but I keep on getting this eror, " Loading input failed: failed parsing source file interface: open interface: The system cannot find the file specified."

The command I'm running is, " mockgen -source=interface.go -destination=mock_interface.go -package=store ".

My project is in my Drive D, and my GOPATH is: " C:\Users\rider\go ".

I have also tried to run my project in the same directory but that doesn't help. How can I make it run?

I'm referring this " https://github.com/gofr-dev/gofr/blob/development/examples/using-mysql/store/mock_interface.go " as a reference, and want to generate the same.

Answer (score 0):

As the error specifies, Mockgen cannot find the "interface.go" file; either try running the command in the same directory where interface.go is situated or try giving the correct path for interface.go in the Mockgen command.

For example, if your directory structure is as follows

[image: Directory Strycture]

You should be running your command in `<path-to-project>/using-mysql/store`

Also, even after this issue is resolved, you might get the error that the source directory is outside GOPATH since your project is on the D drive and GOPATH points to `C:\Users\rider\go`; for this, you can try pointing your GOPATH to the current working directory or moving your projects to the `\go` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem on windows and I solved it by using absolute paths. But I'm not really sure about the cause of this problem, so I hope some of you guys can help me to explain it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmJq1.png)

Comment: Not even understand about your concern